# Concatenate '$' with numeric value

Tags: sql-server-2005, gridview, type-conversion

The SelectCommand for my GridView is as follows:

```
SELECT
  pubName AS Publication,
  COUNT(*) AS Total,
  SUM(CAST (price as INT)) AS Price 
FROM [SecureOrders]
WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY pubName
```

Where I'm doing the SUM AS Price bit, I want to add a dollar sign ($) to the start, so my data displays as $109, instead of just 109. I tried just doing '$' + SUM, but of course that didn't work. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like in many languages, the plus sign is an overloaded operator in T-SQL - addition or string concatenation. When any of the types involved in the operation are numeric, precedence goes to addition. Of course you can't add strings and numbers in a meaningful way, so you get an error about conversion. In order to concatenate the values as strings, you must tell SQL Server that they're all strings. One way to do this is using `CONVERT`:

```
..., '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), SUM(CAST(price AS INT))) AS Price FROM ...
```

Note that in Denali you will be able to avoid the converts by using the new [`CONCAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515%28SQL.110%29.aspx) function, which treats all types as strings and even treats `NULL` values as empty strings.

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit I don't know what you mean. There is no comma between the `$` and the concatenated value. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did, and it didn't work - I'm using Sql Server 2005 by the way - it says incorrect syntax.

Comment: I think it's because the original code sample had a typo. Try changing `CAST price AS INT` to `CAST(price AS INT)`... corrected.

Comment: What does "breaks my code" mean? What code? How? If the consuming application is expecting a numeric type, then maybe you should add the `$` at presentation time instead of in the query. Or correct the type declaration in the code. Or strip out the `$` when the code does any numerical operations. But at the very least, don't just say "doesn't work" or "breaks"...

Comment: I'm sorry - what I meant to say was I still get an incorrect syntax error when I add in that extra parentheses. I didn't realize beforehand that I forgot to add in the closing parentheses. Now it is working 100
%