# Update a column which is in money datatype by concatenating with '$' symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called TABLE_A which has a column called Unitcost that is in money datatype, I have to update Unitcost by ((Cost/Pack)*Count) where these Cost,Pack and Count are other columns in TABLE_A

```
Note: Unitcost  is Money 
      Cost is  Money 
      Pack is int
      Count is nvarchar
```

TABLE_A final output should be like this with updated Unitcost

```
ID   |  Cost  |  Pack  | Count  |  Unitcost 
----------------------------------------------
01   | 12     | 1      |  1     |  $12

01   | 12     | 2      |  1     |  $6

01   | 40     | 4      |  2     |  $20

01   | 12     | 1      |  2     |  $24
```

'$' symbol should come in the Unitcost  column with value. I need a query. plz help.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485423/concatenate-with-numeric-value

Comment: You cannot add a symbol/character for a column defined as `Money` datatype .

Comment: Also the $ is a display concern? Perhaps your column should be UnitcostInDollars and loose the $ prefix then you can use it as a Money datatype... Or perhaps include a new column called Currency that just includes the $ symbol...

Comment: A SQL query is supposed to provide you with *raw* data, not with how they should *look* on your screen. It is the presentation layer (i.e. most likely your application) that should take care about formatting the output.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is NO, you cannot store $ inside a money column. It can be proved with the code below:

```
declare @UnitCost money = '$3,257.14'
select @UnitCost -- It works but symbols like $ and , are removed. 3257.14 is returned in this case.
```

The code snippet below is not what you have asked for, but may just give you some ideas:

```
declare @UnitCost money = '3257.14'
select '$' + convert(varchar, @UnitCost, 1) -- Returns $3,257.14 as varchar.
```

Now, I would like to recommend that you stay away from the money/smallmoney data types, despite what the names suggest, they don't really offer any more value for financial calculations than the decimal data type. Money/smallmoney are also known to suffer from integer divisions. Refer to [Throw Your MONEY Away](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/throw-your-money-away.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can not   update Unitcost Column with $ value which is having money datatype . 
you need to append $ to  Unitcost Column when u write a Select Query. your select query would be like this.

```
select ID ,    Cost,    Pack,   Count,  '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Unitcost ) AS Unitcost from TABLE_A
```

Other important note Your Unitcost  column is based on other column multiplication.no need to create a  Unitcost column in tabel as it is based on other column multiplication.you can use this select query as well

```
select ID ,    Cost,    Pack,   Count,  '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ((Cost/Pack)*Count) ) AS Unitcost from TABLE_A
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET Unitcost = ((Cost/Pack)*Count)

SELECT ID, Cost, Pack, Count, 
'$' + CAST(Unitcost AS VARCHAR(50)) AS Unitcost
FROM TABLE_A
```

This assumes Pack is never zero, though.